# How can I use breakpoint inside services.AddScoped lambda?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a Service with a `LinkId` dependency:

```
services.AddScoped(sp =>
{
    var linkId = sp.GetService<Services.ILinkProvider>().LinkId;
    return new Service(linkId);
});
```

I get an exception:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Primitives.LinkId' while attempting to activate 'Service'.

I disable "Just My Code", set breakpoint on `var linkId...` line, but it never breaks.

Comment: can you check if you're building in debug mode..are there some pdb's in the bin folder?

Comment: yes, breakpoint on `services.AddScoped...` line works

Comment: Does your implementation of `ILinkProvider` has depedencies too and are these dependencies registered too?

Comment: It has `ISession` dependency. Its resolved. But this not the question, I want to debug `Service` creation.